# nginx: [emerg] unknown "bytes_received" variable

Tags: nginx

I try to log the amount of bytes received from a client in Nginx like so:

```
log_format postdata '$remote_addr sent $bytes_received bytes';
```

However, I get the following error when attempting to start the service:

```
nginx: [emerg] unknown "bytes_received" variable
```

As far as I can see this variable should be present from Nginx 1.11.4. I run 1.13.9:

```
#:/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.13.9
```

Output of nginx -V:

```
:~# /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V
nginx version: nginx/1.13.9
built by gcc 5.4.0 20160609 (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.9)
built with OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
TLS SNI support enabled
configure arguments: --with-http_ssl_module --with-pcre --with-http_realip_module --with-stream --add-module=../nchan
```

Is there something I am missing here?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: what is the output of `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -t` ?

Comment: @TarunLalwani: 
nginx: [emerg] unknown "bytes_received" variable
nginx: configuration file /usr/local/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test failed

Comment: That is really weird. Please also add output of `/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -V`

Comment: @TarunLalwani I have added it to the post above. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

**PS: Using answers as comments as I need to post large text**

Seems like you have it compiled from source and a required module is missing. I have below output on the same

> configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -fPIE -pie -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-ipv6 --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_addition_module --with-http_dav_module --with-http_geoip_module --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module --with-stream --with-stream_ssl_module --with-mail --with-mail_ssl_module --with-threads

So make sure you have all the `stream` modules at least and may be some other module is a pre-requisite for this to work

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your answer and give feedback! PS: I did not give you the downvote.

Comment: I fail to understand people's reasoning to downvote this answer. Anyway I up-voted to balance it out. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

[`$request_length`](https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#var_request_length) may be what you want:

> request length (including request line, header, and request body)

This logs the size of the request received from the client without hitting the unknown variable issue, if you're using a build of Nginx which doesn't have `ngx_stream_core_module` built in.

In other words `$request_length` (rather than `$bytes_received`) seems to be the counterpart to `$bytes_sent`, somewhat confusingly.